# How to customize drupal node using 'PANELS'

Tags: nodes

I am trying to implement the "PANELS" module in drupal 7.31 to customize a page display.

Panels Module : 7.x-3.4

Drupal version : 7.31

I have created courses(as a product) using "COMMERCE" module. I am able to display the LIST Courses
using Panels. But I am also want to customize the course detail page(User click on course and then redirect to detail page).

You can see list of courses using Panels on here:

[image]

Now I want to customize the detail page where all details show from Database using Panels.

You can also see Course Detail page here:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are asking. I tend to use View modes to customize content output, and then have Panels display that output. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the node detail page with panels. You will have to use [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds). DS allows you to do a lot of things, and one of them is "Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface."

Hope this helps